# Question about convergence in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

For part a) my strategy was showing that since E is sequentially compact, by the Borel-Lebesgue theorem it is compact. For part b) I am not sure how to solve the problem. Can I simply use the sequential definition of continuity to get an answer, or is it more complicated than that? Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

It’s also very easy to prove (a) from the definition of compactness: if $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $E$, there is a $U_0\in\mathscr{U}$ that contains $x_\infty$, and by the definition of convergence $E\setminus U_0$ is finite.

Yes, for (b) you can use the fact that in metric spaces continuity is equivalent to sequential continuity. Just combine that with (a), and the result falls out pretty quickly.

Comment: How do I know that for any point x in X there is a sequence of points converging to x was my only concern ? Suppose X contains an isolated point, do I need to worry about this ?

Comment: @Geo17: No, that’s not a problem: a sequence converges to an isolated point if and only if it’s eventually constant at the isolated point, so you always have such sequences – they’re just not very interesting.

Comment: thanks so much, I totally understand now

Comment: @Geo17: You’re very welcome.